# WordPress plugins for PayWalls and Subscription Models With International Payment Gateway

Tags: php, wordpress, payment-gateway, subscription

I am looking for a solution to my WordPress problem.

I want to build an information site where guests can access free content. They can also access paid content on either a:

1. Pay-as-you-read basis or;
2. Daly, Weekly and Monthly subscription basis.

How do I approach this? Is anyone aware of a plugin that can fulfil these needs? The plugin must be able to accept any international payment gateways. Most I have found are restricted to PayPal and Stripe. In my country, only consumers can use PayPal to pay for stuff, merchants cannot accept payments.

I would like to be pointed to a plugin that can fulfill all above requirements. If such does not exist, is there any other approach to achieving my purpose? Perhaps some code inherent in WordPress that can help me do these manually?

Thank you.

Comment: How about Paid Memberships Pro?

Answer (score 1):

The most used plugin for payments in WordPress is definetly Woocommerce. In 2012 they released something called Woocommrce Subscriptions: http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/

I didn't used it so I don't know if it helps you, but you can look into it. Good luck.

Answer (score -4):

Your want this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/membership/ You can create different member groups and set authority. And Paypal(or popular payment gateways) included in this plugin.

Comment: Membership does not allow manual/international payment gateways. PayPal is not available to merchants in my region

Comment: okey, which payment gateway avaible in your country? Does not support it **Membership**?

Comment: None of the gateways membership accepts in available in my country.

Comment: then you must create custom pos module.